# using go quickstart for google-drive-api doesn't work

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm using the getting started guide in the go [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/go). I seem to have followed all the steps, but keep getting an error when prompted for the token. Using the python quickstart guide, I am able to connect fine, so I don' believe it is a problem with credentials.

Once it goes through the authorization flow, it seems to redirect to a url without any port, and sure enough the credentials.json has the "redirect_uris":["http://localhost"

I see the python example is using the InstalledApp method for the token flow, as opposed to the golang version that uses...

any ideas?

Tried the following code:

authURL := config.AuthCodeURL("state-token", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
fmt.Printf("Go to the following link in your browser then type the "+
"authorization code: \n%v\n", authURL)

```
    var authCode string
    if _, err := fmt.Scan(&authCode); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Unable to read authorization code %v", err)
    }

    tok, err := config.Exchange(context.TODO(), authCode)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve token from web %v", err)
    }
```

browser grant permission came up

Redirected to localhost: with no port info

Failed with: "invalid_grant" "Malformed auth code."

Comment: Please include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.